# WP7/Silverlight: Inactive Buttons inside a ScrollViewer with IsHitTestVisible=False… inside a Pivot

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, scrollviewer

I was making some good progress on my App, but ran into a problem that's stumped me. I was hoping someone could offer their expertise?

My app is intended to be a "scoresheet"... one of the PivotItems features a ScrollViewer (Horizontal scrolling, vertical disabled), with a Horizontal-orientation StackPanel inside. This StackPanel contains a "ScoreSheet" UserControl, which is basically a Grid with various text-boxes on it.  So... kind of like this (except the ScoreSheet items are added to the StackPanel programmatically):

```
<controls:PivotItem>
   <controls:PivotItem.Header>
      <TextBlock Text="score sheet" FontSize="45" Height="80" />
   </controls:PivotItem.Header>

   <ScrollViewer Width="470" Height="560" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="sv_scoresheets" MaxHeight="560" MinHeight="560" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" IsHitTestVisible="False">
      <StackPanel Name="sp_scoresheets" Orientation="Horizontal">
         <local:ScoreSheet></local:ScoreSheet>
         <local:ScoreSheet></local:ScoreSheet>
         <local:ScoreSheet></local:ScoreSheet>
      </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>

</controls:PivotItem>
```

The concept was that "Previous" and "Next" buttons are in the ApplicationBar at the bottom of the page, and they trigger an Animation of the ScrollViewer left or right (ie. Current Round * Width of ScoreSheet).  By having "IsHitTestVisible" set to "False" on the ScrollViewer, a user can't manually move the displayed ScoreSheet to a weird position, and swiping left/right between PivotItems still works as expected.

That all worked nicely. :)

However... the problem is on the ScoreSheet control, I want a few Buttons and TextBoxes so the user can enter in a score into the grid. By having "IsHitTestVisible" on the ScrollViewer, the taps/etc. just get ignored.

I tried setting "IsHitTestVisible" to "True" and instead running a function on the ScrollViewer's ManipulationStarted event (calling "e.Complete()")... but although that lets me access controls inside the ScoreSheet, I can't swipe left/right between PivotItems anymore.

So… can anyone help?  I was thinking maybe I could refine the ManipulationStarted behavior somehow, maybe "passing along" the action to the Pivot control instead of having the ScrollViewer move?  Or some other way I can make the ScrollViewer "inactive" but allow the controls within to be interactive?

I'd really appreciate any help.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Paul for his input and advice.  A Pivot offered some extra flexibility, but still had similar issues to the ScrollViewer control when IsHitTestVisible="False" (in that buttons and other controls on the contained elements would become unusable).  Also, aesthetically for this app, I found I preferred the multiple ScoreSheets being right next to each other when the Previous/Next buttons were pressed and they were animated to show the new sheet (as PivotItems, one would scroll out of view before the next scrolled into place).

After some more thought and experimentation, I achieved the desired effect like this:

```
<Canvas Width="470" Height="560" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="560" MinHeight="560" MinWidth="470" MaxWidth="470">
   <Canvas.Clip>
      <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,470,560" />
   </Canvas.Clip>
   <StackPanel Name="sp_scoresheets" Orientation="Horizontal" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
      <local:ScoreSheet /></local:ScoreSheet>
      <local:ScoreSheet /></local:ScoreSheet>
      <local:ScoreSheet /></local:ScoreSheet>
   </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

The "Canvas.Clip" let me hide the ScoreSheets on either side of the currently visible one, and I could animate the Canvas.Left position of the StackPanel when the Previous/Next buttons were pressed.

By avoiding the ScrollViewer or Pivot, there were no events to handle/override, and the controls in the StackPanel could then be accessed as I intended.

'hopefully that might be of help to others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would say that your intended usage of the scrollviewer breaks the intended design of the scrollviewer and the pivot (a common mistake windows phone developers, including myself, have made). The main reason this is generally considered a bad practice is that it implements a side ways navigation paradigm that is intended to *only* be provided by the Pivot control and the Panorama control.

With that said, it doesn't mean your particular use is 100% bad, I think that there are times when breaking the rules is okay. I would just encourage you to do some research and really make sure you're not going to confuse the user, or force them to learn a navigation paradigm that they are not already familiar with through the phone's operating system, and apps that properly make use of the controls provided by the SDK.

Okay, so now that's out of the way, if you determine this really is the best design for your app, you'll need to do the following to accomplish what you want:

### Instead of Using a Horizontal ScrollViewer, use a Pivot control inside your Pivot control

You'll need create a header template that is essentially empty so that you don't take up any space in the upper area of inner scrolling section.

This also makes a lot more sense because the horizontal scrolling you are trying to accomplish is by "section" instead of a continuous scroll. This saves you the trouble of having to think about exactly how many pixels you are scrolling (instead you can just use XAML to change the width of your PivotItems

### Disable the scrolling functionality of the pivot scroll by the user

This can be done a number of different ways of varying complexity, and almost warrants a question on it's own. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2010/11/22/preventing-the-pivot-or-panorama-controls-from-scrolling.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) for one way to accomplish this.

Another thing to do (which gives you more control) is to capture the `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationDelta`, and `ManipulationCompleted` events on the inner pivot item. **if** you detect the delta manipulation containing a horizontal component, then inside the method handler for the `ManipulationDelta` event, set `e.Handled = true`. To cancel the inner Pivot's ability to handle the horizontal scrolling. That will look something like the following:

```
// Event handler for ManipulationDelta event on your inner Pivot control
public void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X != 0)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

As you will discover, this can provide some odd behavior. Ideally, you'll want to figure out what works best for your app, but typically you want to check for more than just != 0 on the X component, and allow the user some little bit of x, just incase they hit the control at a weird angle such that the X component has a value of 1.

### Implementing the buttons to move to the right or the left:

This should be pretty simple, just make use of the Pivot.SelectedIndex property.

**However, in *most* cases, this is a bad idea. Be REALLY sure you are a good exception to standard practice (preferably by giving your app to someone who has never used it but owns a windows phone, and see if they intuitively understand how to use your app.**

Comment: Thanks Paul; great read. Point taken about adhering to the UI standards… I'm reasonably confident, though, that I'm not breaking things by having the "scoresheets" inside the ScrollViewer… so long as the user can still swipe left/right to move between PivotItems (hence the IsHitTestEnabled="False" on the ScrollViewer I attempted).The problem was that the items inside then couldn't be interacted with - but I'll try tonight the approach with the "Inner Pivot" you propose, as I've noticed before that controls still work on my main Pivot even if I set IsHitTestEnabled="False". Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Paul… a follow-up to this: I changed it to use a custom-styled Pivot control (with no header) - which I called "ssPivot" - and hooked the ApplicationBar buttons up to set ssPivot.SelectedIndex. This worked, but unfortunately I still ran into the problem of the controls in the PivotItems not working if ssPivot.IsHitTestEnabled="False". Using the ManipulationDelta approach sort-of worked, but ran into the "odd behavior" you mentioned (ssPivot stopping "half-way" between items, for example); still, I'll explore more on this. ...

Comment: ... I'll check the link you included, but it seems to be preventing the "outer pivot" from scrolling, whereas I want the reverse (to prevent the "inner pivot" from scrolling).  Another approach I was thinking was to do away with a ScrollViewer/Pivot entirely (taking their default behaviors out entirely), and put a StackPanel (containing the ScoreSheets) inside a Canvas maybe, with a negative Margin which I'd manipulate with the ApplicationBar buttons to move the items into view(?). I'll have to experiment some more. Either way, this has been quite a learning experience - thank you again!